# Determine if a PHP resource contains binary or text

Tags: php, mongodb, resources, gridfs

I am using `MongoDB` and storing files into `GridFS` using `PHP`. I am pulling files out via:

```
$mongo = new Mongo;
$images = $monogo->my_db->getGridFS('images');
$image = $images->findOne('epic-beard-man.png');
$stream = $image->getResource();
```

Which is cool, because `$stream` is a PHP `resource`. The thing I need, is to determine if the stream/resource is binary or text. If it is text, I want to output it, otherwise if it is binary, I don't want to output it.

Is there a magical function like: `is_binary($stream)`

**EDIT**

```
echo get_resource_type($stream);
```

Returns `STREAM`. Hum, not very useful.

Comment: Binary and so called "Plain text" are the same things. It's just that in plain text you can actually read it, because the bytes there make sense for humans, and in "binary" it's not. Does mean it's any different for the computer.

Comment: Sure, but in my app, text should be outputted, but binary files should just say (This is a binary file...) and not output all the binary data, because they can be huge.

Comment: another good reason not to store files in a db

Comment: MongoDB and GridFS are actually really nice. Love that I can store meta data right with the actual bytes, and query on the meta-data. Plus with replica-sets the files are distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot check this without actually reading from the resource. You can read the whole thing and look for non-printable characters (which should happen pretty fast if it is an image). You can check for "printability" with [ctype_print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-print.php), which will unfortunately return `false` for tabs and newlines, so it may not be the best one after all. You can also build your own regex to check the data:

```
preg_match(':^(\P{Cc}|[\t\n])*$:', $data)
```

The best and easiest thing to do is however to save the data type, possibly the MIME type, together with the object. That way you do not need to do anything magic at display time.

I think that schemaless databases like MongoDB needs at least as much care in the design stage as relational databases. This is a typical thing to think about when designing a database: what type do my data have?

Comment: I am reading it like: `while (!feof($stream)) { $data .= fread($stream, 8192); }` How can I check `$data`?

Comment: `ctype_print` won't work, because text files can have newlines, tabs, etc.

Comment: I realised that as well and added a regex.